# Material Design Icons displays opposite icons

Tags: angular, icons, material-design

I have self hosted material icons installed.
Most icons display OK. But several do not. For example:

```
<mat-icon >update_disabled</mat-icon>
```

and instead the *'update_disabled'* icon, the browser displays is the *'update'* icon.

Similarly, some other icons, especially those with the hyphen character display different icons, either their 'parent' icon, with the name before the '_' character or a different icon.